# Unable to login in my gcloud compute engine xrdp using Remote Desktop

Tags: google-compute-engine, x11, rdp, xfce, xrdp

Hello i have installed xrdp and xfce4 on my gcloud compute engine. below is the process for installation:

i had a user with name myadav on the ubuntu 16.04 server:

so i first install xrdp by :

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

and then i installed :

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

then i perform some command for initiating xrdp and xfce4:

```
echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession
sudo vim /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
```

Add the following lines at the end of the file:

```
. /etc/X11/Xsession 
. /usr/bin/startxfce4
sudo service xrdp restart
```

Now when i use windows RDP and type my external ip i get a xrdp login screen. My problem is that, when i type username as myadav which is a ubuntu user, unable to login. What is the username and password for login into my system. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the user account that is to be used for logging in is a member of the tsusers group (this is a group that should be created by the XRDP program).
sudo usermod –a –G tsusers ‘username’

You can also try to troubleshoot the problem by editing the [xrdp.ini](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-xrdp.ini/) configuration file.There are options for passwords where you can set a password:
`password=<password>|ask`
Specifies the password used for authenticating in the connection. If set to ask, password should be provided in the login window.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I will try and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is here looking out for others answers than the above accepted answer, you could try below which in fact worked for me.

- if you have not setup a password for root user please do so using `sudo passwd`.
- use username as `root and your setup password for login to the system.